# Problema al Exportar Base de Datos MySQL a Excel con PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysqli, phpexcel

Estoy tratando de exportar la tabla de mi base de datos mysql utilizando la librería PHPExcel, pero esta no me genera nada.

Tengo este enlace con el que hago el llamado a el archivo exportar:

```
<a href="exportar.php">Descargar tabla</a>
```

y tengo este archivo exportar.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

 $conexion = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx");
 mysqli_select_db ("xxxxx", $conexion);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM solicitudes ORDER BY folio DESC";
 $resultado = mysqli_query ($sql, $conexion) or die (mysqli_error ());
 $registros = mysqli_num_rows ($resultado);

 if ($registros > 0) {
   require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

   //Informacion del excel
   $objPHPExcel->
    getProperties()
        ->setCreator("lahuerta")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("lahuerta")
        ->setTitle("Exportar Base de Datos")
        ->setSubject("Tabla")
        ->setDescription("Documento generado con PHPExcel")
        ->setKeywords("lahuerta  con  phpexcel")
        ->setCategory("solicitudes");    

   $i = 1;    
   while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_object ($resultado)) {

      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $registro->name);

      $i++;

   }
}
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="tabla.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter=PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
mysql_close ();
?>
```

Al momento de la ejecución me muestra las siguientes advertencias:

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/exportar.php on line 7

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/exportar.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/exportar.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los errores surgen debido a que el **orden de los parámetros** pasados a las funciones [`mysqli_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php), [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php) y [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) es incorrecto.

La solución, es simplemente pasar `$conexion` como primer parámetro.

Ejemplo:

```
mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "xxxxx");
$resultado = mysqli_query ($conexion, $sql) or die (mysqli_error ($conexion));
```

Comment: ya corregi, pero ahora me manda este mensaje muchisimas veses..     Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in /home/exportar.php on line 32

Comment: y al final me da un Fatal error:           Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /home/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 220

Comment: suena como la ruta mal direccionada

Comment: @SharlyInfinitywars, estos son nuevos errores, que son producto de haber corregido exitosamente los errores anteriores.Para poder responderte es necesario saber datos que no has publicado en la pregunta, como por ejemplo: la estructura de la tabla `solicitudes` y la version de `PHP` y si tiene activada la extensión `Zip`. Te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta para este nuevo escenario.

Comment: ok.. formulare la nueva pregunta